# Replacing a specific charcater in a .txt file

Tags: text, vbscript

My .txt file reads "203,13,58,2018,0" all I need to do is replace the 0 at the end with a 1.

I found several variations of this:

I had code here but the site wont let me post saying the format is off, I'm just frustrated and neew some help here is the site that had the code I've been trying to use. (https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-replace.html)

But they all delete everything else leaving my file with only ",1". What am I missing?

Comment: Did you see the example? you need to pass arguments when you call the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using same code, but adapted:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,strFilename,strSearch,strReplace,objFile,oldContent,newContent

strFilename="D:\demo.txt"
strSearch=",0"
strReplace=",1"

'Does file exist?
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso.FileExists(strFilename)=false then
   wscript.echo "file not found!"
   wscript.Quit
end if

'Read file
set objFile=fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename,1)
oldContent=objFile.ReadAll

'Write file
newContent=replace(oldContent,strSearch,strReplace,1,-1,0)
set objFile=fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename,2)
objFile.Write newContent
objFile.Close
```

Comment: You're welcome!  P.S.: For the down-voter, a comment would have been appreciated!